# Azure Virtual Gateway not using Route table

Tags: azure, routing, openvpn

In Azure, I have set up a virtual network and a gateway which is connected to an on-premise gateway. I have also set up a VM running OpenVPN Access Server. I have added a user-defined route to route traffic to the OpenVPN access server. Still, traffic from the on-premise gateway does not reach the openvpn access server.

[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx8MX.png)

I need to reach the OpenVPN client from the IPSec client, but I can't. I've used tcpdump on the OpenVPN server and I cannot see any traffic reaching it when trying to ping the OpenVPN client from the IPSec client.

```
IPSec client -> OpenVPN server = OK
IPSec client -> Azure VM = OK
IPSec client -> OpenVPN client = NOT WORKING
Azure VM -> OpenVPN client = OK
Azure VM -> IPSec client = OK
```

It seems to me like the Azure Virtual Gateway is not using the route table and the user-defined route, but the Azure VM does. Is there a reason why the azure gateway does not use the user-defined route?

The Azure Virtual Gateway is basic SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was in the OpenVPN Access Server configuration. The iptables configuration did not allow traffic from external subnets to the VPN clients. I solved this by adding the subnet behind the IPSec client to Routing under VPN Settings in OpenVPN Access Server.